# When to use C++ and when to use blueprints?

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I'm trying to learn how to use the Unreal Engine. I have basic knowledge of C++. Recently I started making a Survival Horror Game as a project that I'm just doing for the learning experience. So far though I've implemented every feature through the Blueprint system.

So my question is for what and when will I use code to improve/make a game in Unreal Engine?

Answer (score 17):

You don't need to use C++ for anything as far as I know. Its more of a matter of preference. If you are a programmer, you might do things faster in code, while some might prefer blueprints.

The runtime performance difference is there, but is usually negligible, so don't have that in mind too much.

Bottom line, ideally, you would prefer C++ when you are writing performance critical sections and use blueprints for higher level interactions. If you are like me, you'd probably prefer writing everything, since visual programming is not something I like so much.

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether you are working in a team or not. If you are the only person developing the project, this is a matter of your preference. If you are a programmer in a team it is a must that you put all logic into C++ and allow artists/level designers to react on events in game via the event system.

Also, for me, writing code is faster, but I can imagine that for some people it is the other way. Visual Studio offers many sophisticated tools like *go to definition*, robust finding options, a much better debugging environment, some refactor options and more. There are no such tools in Blueprints or they are much more basic which makes things like complex networks a pain to modify and change.

If you find C++ hard or you don't feel comfortable with it, start your first projects with Blueprints. After you're done, you will know engine better and will feel comfortable with blueprints, this will be a good moment to start to develop in C++.